# Creating accessibility PPTs

Tags: pptxgenjs

Currently there are two accessibility issues with the PPTs generated by PptGenJS:

1. Slides don't have titles;
2. There's no way to indicate row or column headings in tables.

I've played with templates in an attempt to define slide titles, but couldn't get it to work.

I've played with Auto-paging in an attempt to have row headers defined, but it didn't work.

Are there are any plans to address these issues? If not, I might give it a go myself.

Comment: The last update on github is from 5 months ago (see: https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS) also that might be a better place to ask, because there is a higher chance of getting the attention of the author, than posting here (Because no one knows, besides then author himself,  if the author reads stackoverflow...)

Comment: Yeah, good call. I just posted on GitHub. Thanks